# call the function named as select value

Tags: jquery

```
<select class='sela' id='simg'>
<option value='imgdisk'>IMG DISK</option>
<option value='imglib'>IMG LIBRARY</option>
<option value='imgweb'>IMG WEB</option>
<option value='video'>VIDEO</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$('#simg').change(function(){
    var a = $(this).val();
    if (a == 'imgdisk'){imgdisk();}
    else if (a == 'imglib'){imglib();}
    else if (a == 'imgweb'){imgweb();}
    else video();
});
```

So I call the function named as select value.
Is there a shorter way? Something like:

```
var a = $(this).val();
a();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a way to do that. What you search is eval function;

```
eval(a +"()");
```

```js
$('#simg').change(function(){
    var a = $(this).val();
    eval(a +"()");
});

function imgdisk(){
  alert('imgdisk function');
}
function imglib(){
  alert('imglib function');
}
function imgweb(){
  alert('imgweb function');
}
function video(){
  alert('video function');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class='sela' id='simg'>
<option value='imgdisk'>IMG DISK</option>
<option value='imglib'>IMG LIBRARY</option>
<option value='imgweb'>IMG WEB</option>
<option value='video'>VIDEO</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming those are global functions use

```
if(window[a] && typeof window[a] === 'function'){
   window[a]();
}
```

If they aren't global , create an object that references the functions:

```
var funcs = {
  imglib: imglib,
  imgweb: imgweb
};

if(funcs[a]){
   funcs[a]();
}
```

This is to avoid the use of ***evil eval()***

Comment: I think it is local scope :)

Comment: @MuratGüner we have no way to know from what is shown and that is why I added 2 scenarios

Comment: eval() is not evil mate. There is no problem to use eval in this scenario. If purpose is making code faster or making it simpler .. then we can use it.

Comment: @MuratGüner it is absolutely not faster, very difficult to test with also since it compiles in a sandbox